Can't subscribe to onPlayerJoined or onPlayerLeft
I'm trying to set up multiplayer for a game I'm currently working on by using the Player Input and Player Input Manager components in Unity, but I'm having trouble with getting information from the onPlayerJoined and onPlayerLeft events. This is what my GameManager/PlayerInputManager looks like: Visual of my Player Input Manager
For the Notification Behavior, I've tried using Send Messages, but I can't acquire the PlayerInput that way, same for Invoke Unity Events, but when I try to use Invoke C Sharp Events, I receive this error: CS0123: No overload for 'OnPlayerJoined' matches delegate 'Action'
Here's the relevant code in my GameManager script.
void Start()
{
    PlayerInputManager.instance.JoinPlayer(0, -1, null);
    PlayerInputManager.instance.JoinPlayer(1, -1, null);
}

void OnEnable()
{
    // Throwing CS0123: No overload for 'OnPlayerJoined' matches delegate 'Action<PlayerInput>'
    //PlayerInputManager.instance.onPlayerJoined += OnPlayerJoined;
    //PlayerInputManager.instance.onPlayerLeft += OnPlayerLeft;
}

void OnDisable() 
{
    //PlayerInputManager.instance.onPlayerJoined -= OnPlayerJoined;
    //PlayerInputManager.instance.onPlayerLeft -= OnPlayerLeft;
}

public void OnPlayerJoined(PlayerInput playerInput)
{
    Debug.Log("A player has joined!");
    /*playerList.Add(playerInput);

    if (PlayerJoinedGame != null)
    {
        PlayerJoinedGame(playerInput);
    }*/
}

void OnPlayerLeft(PlayerInput playerInput)
{
    Debug.Log("A player left the game.");
}

Please help!

Is there perhaps another class in your project named PlayerInput.  It might be seeing the wrong class.  You can try fully qualifying the parameter to ensure the correct class is being referenced.  I think this is the correct class: UnityEngine.InputSystem.Plugins.PlayerInput.PlayerInput

the error you commented, shows that OnPlayerJoined doesnt match Action, so what is PlayerInputManager definition of this?

Can you share your 'PlayerInputManager' script just to check the implementation of 'onPlayerJoined' and 'onPlayerLeft'

@swsoft You should post your last "edit" as an answer, rather than an edit. Self-answering questions are encouraged, and it's a signal to the rest of the community that the question has been solved.

I had set my InputActions asset to be named PlayerInput. Changing the name solved the issue, thank you everyone!
p.s. I tried to mark an answer but as all responses were comments I could not; thank you hijinxbassist

Next time, if someone gives a useful reply, you can ask them to make an answer before making them as accepted.
